WorldPop Google Earth Engine values when reducing resolution
I want to export a global world population map based on the WorldPop data ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop") in 2020, with lower resolution  (1km) instead of 100m. I used the following code and expect the output raster file to show the population per km2. However, when I opened it on ArcGIS, the maximum value is 7205 (people/km2), but when I searched the highest population density is a lot higher than this number. For example, Manila(43,064), Bogotá(26,141). Is there anything wrong when I tried to resample(reduce region) the data?
// Define world region
var WORLD = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-180, 88, 0, 88, 180, 88, 180, -60, 0, -60, -180, -60], null, false);

// Load the WorldPop dataset 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop");

// First mosaic, then reduce resolution
var year2020 = dataset
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
  .select('population')
  .mosaic()
  .unmask(0)  // Fill missing values with 0
  .clip(WORLD);  // Clip to world region

// Set default projection before reducing resolution
year2020 = year2020.setDefaultProjection({
  crs: 'EPSG:4326', // Coordinate reference system
  scale: 100 // Set scale (100m for the original resolution)
});

// Reduce resolution for summation
var year2020_1km_sum = year2020
  .reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),  // Sum population in each 1km cell
    maxPixels: 1024
  })
  .reproject({
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 1000  // Reproject to 1km scale
  });

// Visualization parameters
var visualization = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['000000', '440154', '3b528b', '21908d', '5dc963', 'fde725']
};

// Display on map
Map.setCenter(0, 0, 2);
Map.addLayer(year2020_1km_sum, visualization, 'Global Population 2020');

// Export with 1km resolution
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: year2020_1km_sum,
  description: 'WorldPop_2020_Global_1km',
  scale: 1000,
  region: WORLD,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326'
});

The map below shows the visualization of the data I exported from the code. Tokyo has a lot lower value compared to informatino I founded (max >15000 per km2)

